# System requirements for high capacity node?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, nodes

I want to build a dedicated geth + parity machine that can have lots of connections to the network. What advice is there for system requirements if I want at most 100 connections? 1000 connections? How do the requirements scale with connection count?

Comment: Get high-speed SSDs 1GB/s+ write with decent capacity 1TB+ and plenty of RAM 64GB+. Bottleneck for both Geth and Parity is Disk I/O. You can circumvent most of it with huge in-memory caching and fast+reliable drives. Connections/Bandwidth are not an issue afaik.

Comment: @5chdn do you know if anyone has run benchmarks with different amount of cache?